# SpecFlow+ Excel Generate Feature File Programmatically

Tags: excel, specflow, feature-file

Given an Excel file, how could a feature file is generated programmatically ?

Using Specflow 2.3.2 and corresponding Excel plugin and dotNet Framework (NOT dotNetCore)

```
string excelPath = @".\CalculatorAdd.feature.xlsx";

ExcelParser excelParser = new ExcelParser( CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture );

var specFlowDoc = excelParser.ParseExcel(excelPath);

// all the scenarios are in this specFlowDoc, 
// just need to export it as feature file, no need to generate code-behind.
// what is next ??
```

Answer (score 0):

FeatureFile is generated using

```
var docFormatter = new SpecFlow.Plus.Excel.SpecFlowPlugin.DocumentFormatter();
string featureFileStr = docFormatter.GetDocumentText(specFlowDoc);
```

Full Code:

```
string excelPath = @".\CalculatorAdd.feature.xlsx";

ExcelParser excelParser = new SpecFlow.Plus.Excel.SpecFlowPlugin.ExcelParser( CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture );
var specFlowDoc = excelParser.ParseExcel(excelPath);

var docFormatter = new SpecFlow.Plus.Excel.SpecFlowPlugin.DocumentFormatter();
string featureFileStr = docFormatter.GetDocumentText( specFlowDoc );
```